# SQLite Trigger Update

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I want to write a trigger in SQLite.

Lets say I have 2 tables A and B

**Computer**

```
int id   
int foo1
```

**Keyboard**

```
int id  
int computerId (foreign key)  
int foo2
```

I want to write a trigger which updates **Keyboard** foo1  when **Computer** foo2  updated.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger 
    AFTER UPDATE OF foo1 ON  Computer  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Keyboard  
         SET foo2 = 'someValue' 
           WHERE computerId = ???? ;
     END;
```

How can i get updated Computer id for where command ? Can someone help me to complete where  command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLITE has NEW and OLD references you can use to obtain current or previous values from the update.  Given your requirement either would probably be usable.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER update_trigger 
    AFTER UPDATE OF foo1 ON  Computer  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE Keyboard  
         SET foo2 = 'someValue' 
           WHERE computerId = OLD.id ;
     END;
```

See **http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html**